# No me funciona correctamente el archivo css vinculado a mi html

Tags: html5, css3

estoy probando nuevos estilos pero a la hora de crearlos en css no me muestra el resultado esperado. Aparentemente veo el código correctamente pero no me crea los 3 recuadros en negro que debería crearme dicho código.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

ESTILOS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
height: 300px;
margin: 240px auto;
}

.container .box{
position: relative;
width: calc(400px-30px);
height: calc(300px-30px);
background: #000;
float: left;
margin: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

He comprobado que reconoce la hoja de estilos correctamente, pero los estilos de la clase hija de "container" llamada "box" no reconoce los estilos. Si necesitais más información pedirla, por favor.

Comment: Por favor pon el html, que veamos lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Hecho. Ya dispones del html y del css

Comment: la gerarqui de las caprtas como esta ?

Comment: Está correctamente. De hecho, detecta los estilos y funciona lo anterior a ".container .box", pero no funciona lo posterior

Comment: Pero lo que quieres hacer es meter lo tres contenedores dentro del grande uno al lado del otro?

Comment: al usar calc siempre poner espacios entre las operaciones `+` `-` `*` `/`, caso contrario puede fallar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo claro, si esto lo que quieres hacer:
Prueba el ejemplo y explica algo mejor lo que crees que no te funciona, y como quieres que se quede.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
background: blue;
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
height: 300px;
margin: 240px auto;
}

.container .box{
background: black;
width: 30%;
height: 90%;
float: left;
margin: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

veo dos cosas;
La primera, agrega espacios a los operadores del calc en el css:

```
calc(400px - 30px)
```

Luego, si usas el calc la recomendación es el uso de porcentajes, si tienes los valores realiza el cálculo y coloca el valor directamente;

```
width: 370px; /*calc(400px - 30px);*/
height: 270px;
```

Saludos,